# ¿como separar n caracteres de un string?

Tags: c

hola tengo que separar una palabra que digite el usuario por ejemplo "hola" en "h", "o", "l", "a" y en cada letra saber cual es la dirección de memoria que tiene cada letra.
Todo esto en lenguaje C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El código a continuación hace la funcionalidad que indica, utiliza un puntero de tipo char que será llenado secuencialmente por los caracteres de los cuales se componga la palabra que el usuario ingrese, posteriormente se calcula la longitud de la cadena de caracteres para iterar sobre estos e imprimirlo como carácter junto a su dirección de memoria en hexadecimal.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char* word;
    int length = 0;

    printf("Palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    length = strlen(word);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%c - %lX\n", word[i], (long)&word[i]);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola lo probe y me aparecio un eror en el printf. //[Error] cast from 'char*' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]

Comment: He actualizado el código fuente, el error se debía a que en una computadora con arquitectura de 64 bits, la precisión de char es de 8 bytes mientras de int es de 4 bytes, para ello he utilizado long (8 
bytes) https://stackoverflow.com/a/17082063/11303292

Comment: hola a que se puede deber que cuando lo compilo en el cmd en mi computador solo me deja ingresar la palabra y despues se termina el programa.

Comment: Debe agregar un system("pause") antes del final del programa si está en ambiente Windows, actualizo el código fuente de mi respuesta.

Comment: ya se soluciono muchas gracias!!!.